# Pulling data from api to excel from a big database

Tags: json, excel, vba

Im using an `API` to pull data to `Excel` and `JSON` parsing to format the data. I have 2 sites from where to get this data. 1 is smaller database with 3000 lines but the other is bigger with hunderds of thousands. Working with the smaller one I get no error and everything works fine but using the same code on bigger database everything juts kind of crashes/hangs up forever.
Code I'm using is surely very faulty and I was told I'm using too many parsings but I'm new to this so can't really figure it out right now.

Code I'm using:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Times()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()
    Dim vResult
    Dim sName
    Dim authKey As String
    authKey = "my_auth_key"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://my_site_url", True
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & authKey
        .send
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid JSON"
        End
    End If
    vResult = vJSON("data")
    JSON.ToArray vResult, aData, aHeader
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    vJSON.Remove "data"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Do Until .Count = 1
            .Item(.Count).Delete
        Loop
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    For Each sName In vJSON
        If IsArray(vJSON(sName)) Or IsObject(vJSON(sName)) Then
            JSON.ToArray vJSON(sName), aData, aHeader
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
                OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
                Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
                .Columns.AutoFit
            End With
            vJSON.Remove sName
        End If
    Next
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader

    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    JSON.Flatten vJSON, vResult
    JSON.ToArray vResult, aData, aHeader

    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Maybe by simplifying and correcting the code my bigger database macro would work as well.

Comment: Why are you writing all that data to excel? Part of the problem is that excel is not built to store this much data. What are you actually doing with this data?

Comment: Analysts need this data in Excel sadly. They need to pull data from 2 different API, filter and analyze them and forward an excel format report.

Comment: It might be more reliable to use powershell to export to CSV. Then they can open the CSV. Is it actually crashing or just taking a long time? Have you let it run to see what happens.

Comment: Using postman it takes max 1min to get the data, in excel I've run the script for 10+ minutes before terminating it, never seen any results. So far we've used postman to get the data, Download the JSON and convert it to XML but this is very annoying for the analysts and want the data to come directly without them converting anything etc. Any ideas how else could i skip the postman/converting part?

Comment: You need a REST tool and postman is as good as any. It’s not necessary to convert to XML though.

Comment: You should be able to convert straight from Json to cab. Json is a pointless format if the data is tabular anyway. REST API’s are a inefficient format for loading bulk data also

Comment: So what you're all saying pulling that data to excel is bad and should look into another soultion? Problem is that these reports need to be filtered and in xls/xlsm format.

Comment: There are 2 APIs, 1 with worker information ( ID, personal_code, name, last name etc ) and another API with workers worktimes. These information keep changeing all the time. worktimes info comes from all over the country from a fingerprint system and gets updated every second. we need to pull data from workers and worktimes, match them together which info we need and create a report. Just watching them and makeing these APis to cab files wouldnt help.

Comment: Depending on the volumes, excel VBA is probably not going to keep up with this unless you are able to pass in a "changed since" parameter, and therefore just capture just "incremental" data. (I mispelt before I meant CSV). I can't advise on what system you should build as there isn't enough information.

Comment: Do you need to remember historical data (i.e. same month last year). Is this API the only way to get data? If I was limited to what you have described I would have one worker in powershell calling the API and constantly dumping data into a database, and a seperate reporting platform pulling data out of the database.

Comment: We need to generate reports pretty much everyday but for 1 month only. Lets say 1dec-15dec-31dec and then again 1jan-31jan etc. As far as i know API is the only way to get that data. With this API we are pulling data from a DB that gets updated constantly. Analysts are not that capable working with databases so we need to make things as simple as possible for them to get the data that they can filter and sort and make a report.

Comment: There are many ways to make a database easily accessible to analysts that can only use excel. One way is to simply export the data to excel every day. I only mention a database because it's going to quickly become very impractical to extract data from a 100K table every day. You need a way to store the data locally, and you need a way to extract the data incrementally (only changed data)